# How to handle additional columns in join tables when using Symfony?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, datamodel

Let's assume I have two Entities in my Symfony2 bundle, `User` and `Group`. Associated by a many-to-many relationship.

```
    ┌────────────────┐         ┌────────────────┐         ┌────────────────┐
    |      USER      |         | USER_GROUP_REL |         |     GROUP      |
    ├────────────────┤         ├────────────────┤         ├────────────────┤
    | id#            ├---------┤ user_id#       |    ┌----┤ id#            |
    | username       |         | group_id#      ├----┘    | groupname      |
    | email          |         | created_date   |         |                |
    └────────────────┘         └────────────────┘         └────────────────┘
```

What would be a good practice or a good approach to add additional columns to the join table, like a created date which represents the date when `User` joined `Group`?

I know that I could use the [`QueryBuilder`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/query-builder.html) to write an `INSERT` statement.

But as far as I have not seen *any* `INSERT` example of QueryBuilder or native SQL which makes me believe that ORM/Doctrine try to avoid direct INSERT statements (e.g. for security reasons). Plus as far as I have understood Symfony and Doctrine I would be taken aback if such a common requirement wouldn't be covered by the framework.

Comment: +1 for nice structure

Comment: Hm, I set User (1-n) UserGroup (n-1) Group when Many-to-many table has extra column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set a property of the relation. This is how it's done in doctrine:
[doctrine 2 many to many (Products - Categories)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913104/doctrine-2-many-to-many-products-categories/18047139)

I answered that question with a use case (like yours).

This is an additional question / answer which considers the benefits and use cases: [Doctrine 2 : Best way to manage many-to-many associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995898/doctrine-2-best-way-to-manage-many-to-many-associations/18046686#18046686)